# C Code Preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a piece of code as below

```
    Local_DATA[0] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 1);
    Local_DATA[1] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 2);
    Local_DATA[2] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 3);
    Local_DATA[3] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 4);
```

I would have to make a preprocessor like

```
    #ifdef ABC
            Local_DATA[0] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 1);
            Local_DATA[1] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 2);
            Local_DATA[2] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 3);
            Local_DATA[3] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 4);
    #else
            Local_DATA[0] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 1));
            Local_DATA[1] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 2));
            Local_DATA[2] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 3));
            Local_DATA[3] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 4));
    #endif
```

I have many lines of code where I have to manually perform this. Is there any way to have something like a macro defined?

Comment: It might be easier to ensure that the data is *always* in network byte order, then you don't need the preprocessor conditional.

Comment: Could you show us what the similar and different parts of each group are? We can't show the best macro without knowing which parts are constant versus variable.

Comment: ntohl is a macro, int32_T is a data type and event_structure and Local_Data are variables.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to do this:

```
   Local_DATA[0] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 1));
   Local_DATA[1] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 2));
   Local_DATA[2] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 3));
   Local_DATA[3] =  ntohl (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 4));
```

As if the network order is the same as the host order `ntohl` will be a macro which is a noop.
Otherwise the `ntohl` will do the necessary operation

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifdef ABC
   #define REF_PTR(s, off) (* ((int32_T *) s + off))
#else
   #define REF_PTR(s, off) (ntohl (* ((int32_T *) s + off)))
#endif

Local_DATA[0] = REF_PTR(event_structure, 1);
// etc
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: In all the ways that is suggested, I would have to make a change to the code 
    Local_DATA[0] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 1);
    Local_DATA[1] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 2);
    Local_DATA[2] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 3);
    Local_DATA[3] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + 4);

For me, I have the above lines existing in the code, Is there a way to retain the above lines and have the macro defined?

Comment: Frankly no there is not!  You can not get the lines to change depending on the definition without invoking the macro somehow on the lines that it is expected to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use a function-style macro:

```
#if ABC
#define MYORDER(x) (x)
#else
#define MYORDER(x) ntohl(x)
#endif
...

Local_DATA[0] =  MYORDER(* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 1));
Local_DATA[1] =  MYORDER(* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 2));
Local_DATA[2] =  MYORDER(* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 3));
Local_DATA[3] =  MYORDER(* ((int32_T *) event_structure + 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>

#ifdef ABC
  #define PROC1(z, n, func) Local_DATA[n] =  * ((int32_T *) event_structure + BOOST_PP_ADD(n, 1));
#else
  #define PROC1(z, n, func) Local_DATA[n] =  func (* ((int32_T *) event_structure + BOOST_PP_ADD(n, 1)));
#endif
#define PROC(func, n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, PROC1, func)

...

PROC(ntohl, 4);
```